# Minimum string in a hash table?

Tags: java, hashtable

Here's my code. I can't figure out why it's not working but it fails with strings GF and LH.

```
private int N;           // number of strings in the hash table
private int M;           // size of linear probing table
private String[] keys;   // the keys

// Returns the minimum string in the table
// Returns null if no such string exists
public String min() {
    // TODO
    String min = keys[0];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {

        if (keys[i].compareTo(min) < 0) {
            min = keys[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Define *not working*

Comment: not clear code to see the error

Comment: `return Collections.min(Arrays.asList(keys));` would be easier.

Comment: Where did you define N?

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice use of Java APIs

Comment: Small note: you can start your loop at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0` since you have already assigned `min` to `keys[0]`

Comment: How does the question relate to hash tables? You appear to be assuming all the keys between 0 and N-1 are not `null` which wouldn't be normal in a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out: using the String length

```
String arr[] = {"hei", "hvordan","as"};
String minni = Arrays.stream(arr).min((String a,String b)-> Integer.compare(a.length(),b.length())).get();
```

using compareTo():

```
String arr[] = {"hei", "hvordan","as"};
String minni = Arrays.stream(arr).min(String::compareTo).get();
```

output:
as

full method:

```
private int N;           // number of strings in the hash table
private int M;           // size of linear probing table
private String[] keys;   // the keys


// Returns the minimum string in the table
// Returns null if no such string exists
String arr[] = {"hei", "hvordan","as"};
public String min() {
    String min = Arrays.stream(arr).min(String::compareTo).get();

    return min;
}
```

Comment: And why do you think that OP want to use the string length as the comparison criterion?

Comment: @Tom it was a suggestion to get the mininum String since he didnt provide much information on how he want to compare them.

Comment: OP provided that information, just look at the code (`keys[i].compareTo(min) < 0`).

Comment: he just used the normal comparison to compare it and that will not give the minimum string out.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion that might help him? @Tom

Comment: I have one for OP and one for your: for OP: read the first comment and do what it says. For you: "Jess" doesn't look like a male name ;P.

Comment: Yes, i saw that but if compare all the Strings with the string on the first index on what criterion? the compare() > 0 use the normal java one and it will not give the right minimum string. example "working"  and "Acoustics" it will take second as mini from the normal Compare() > 0

Comment: Yea @Tom i know but i will compare the two String with the normal java comapare > 0 criterion and the minimum will not be the correct one.

Comment: You mean `compareTo() < 0` (not `> 0`) and it means that the left string is "smaller" then the right one. The only problem is that OPs code doesn't correctly compare each item with the others. It would need a sorted array and it wouldn't make much sense use OPs code, if it is already sorted.

Comment: Yea @Tom negative int if a < b and Positive int if a > b

Comment: @Tom using String minni = Arrays.stream(arr).min((String a,String b)-> a.compareTo(b)).get(); will get the minimum. i think this will help him

Comment: `Arrays.stream(keys).min(String::compareTo).get()` is enough. And you mean "her" ;P.

Comment: @Tom yea. is shorter

Comment: @Tom Hey, thanks you were right. the compareTo works. Thanks for calling my attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change N in the for loop to M. M is the actual size of the array, N is the number of items. Then you have to consider the case of a an index being null because it is a hashtable. Good luck.